# SQL Server command in vb.net not working cause all in one sentence

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, insert, sql-update

This is propably a very easy question.

But i cant fix it.
I try an update if @ID = column id, else insert all.

Only this one doesn't work if i put it all in one sentence

```
Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Locatie SET (Longitude = @Longitude, Latitude = @Latitude, Timestamp = @Timestamp) WHERE ID=@ID IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO Locatie VALUES (@ID, @Longitude, @Latitude, @Timestamp)"
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: You have tagged sql-server but i assume you are using MySQL because of the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work just fine

```
Cmd.CommandText = "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Locatie WHERE Id = @Id) " & Environment.NewLine & _
                  "  BEGIN UPDATE Locatie SET Longitude = @Longitude, Latitude = @Latitude, Timestamp = @Timestamp WHERE ID=@Id END " & Environment.NewLine & _
                  "ELSE " & Environment.NewLine & _
                  "   BEGIN INSERT INTO Locatie VALUES (@ID, @Longitude, @Latitude, @Timestamp) END "
```

Although you are probably better off (for maintainability) using a stored procedure.

Comment: In vb.net a enter is a new line of code.. So this doesnt work

Comment: @Babboe, you can in VB.Net do like this `"text" & vbNewLine & "More text"`, you can event do a new line in code after the `&` to keep it nice and formatted.

Answer (score 1):

try the below:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Locatie SET (Longitude = @Longitude, Latitude = @Latitude, Timestamp = @Timestamp) WHERE ID=@ID GO IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 begin INSERT INTO Locatie VALUES (@ID, @Longitude, @Latitude, @Timestamp) end Go"
```